# CSS How to change 3 line (menu icon) color when hover

Tags: css

Im creating a drop-down menu and added menu icon to let user know this is clickable. However, when I hover the menu icon the color doesn't change to the color I want. I tried `.box-shadow-menu:hover` but nothing happen.

**IN HTML**

```
    <ul class="navigation"> 
    <a style="padding-left:33px;" class="main" href="#url">
    The Smile<b class="box-shadow-menu"></b>

    </a>

    <li class="n"><a style="padding-left:30px;" href="#">One</a>
    </li>
    <li><a style="padding-left:30px;" href="#">Two</a>
    </li>
    <li class="n"><a style="padding-left:30px;" href="#">Three</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Menu icon CSS**

```
.box-shadow-menu {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.box-shadow-menu:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0.25em;
    width: 1em;
    height: 0.15em;
    background: #1ABC9C;
    box-shadow: 0 0.25em 0 0 #1ABC9C, 0 0.5em 0 0 #1ABC9C;
}
```

[image]

[Here the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47us3pq6/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:-

```
ul.navigation:hover .box-shadow-menu:before{
     background-color:#333;
     box-shadow:0 0.25em 0 0 #333, 0 0.5em 0 0 #333;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/47us3pq6/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

change background and box-shadow with the color you want

```
    .navigation:hover  .box-shadow-menu:before {
    background: #1ABC9C;
    box-shadow: 0 0.25em 0 0 #1ABC9C, 0 0.5em 0 0 #1ABC9C;
}
```